# ActiveMQ-Client osgi bundle?

Tags: java, osgi, activemq-classic, osgi-bundle

i was searching for a ready to use osgi bundle of activemq-client (5.9.0>=). It seems like the jar manifest does not contain any OSGi markup by default.

I also came across the activemq-osgi bundle - which contains way too much stuff i will not need and also has some runtime dependencies on j2ee components as it seems.

Is there any pre-packaged activemq-client bundle or do i have to wrap it myself?

I am trying to install it to a felix container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that you are trying to install the ActiveMQ 5.9 client into Karaf. For this it is not the activemq-client jar that is used but activemq-osgi. It however, does have its own dependencies. The simplest way to install it is through the features mechanism in Karaf:

```
features:addUrl mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/5.9.0/xml/features
features:install activemq-client
```

The full list of dependencies is as follows:

```
Feature contains followed bundles:
 mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec/1.1.1 start-level=50
 mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jta_1.1_spec/1.1.1 start-level=50
 mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-jms_1.1_spec/1.1.1 start-level=50
 mvn:org.apache.geronimo.specs/geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec/1.0.1 start-level=50
 mvn:org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics-runtime/0.6.4 start-level=50
 mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl/2.2.1.1_2 start-level=50
 mvn:commons-pool/commons-pool/1.6 start-level=50
 mvn:commons-net/commons-net/3.3 start-level=50
 wrap:mvn:org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5$Import-Package=*;resolution:=optional&Export-Package=org.apache.zookeeper*;-noimport:=true&overwrite=merge start-level=50
 mvn:org.apache.xbean/xbean-spring/3.14 start-level=50
 mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-osgi/5.9.0 start-level=50
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look under spring ebr repo? There are quite a few there, I can't see the 5.9.0 though :(